# Is there a long irregular adjective in its base (positive or plain) form?

Tags: adjectives

As I remember from grammar lessons, adjectives are classified into **regular** and **irregular** (are totally different in their base form and comparative form, such as bad and worse), and into short (one syllable) and long (two syllables).

My question is if there is an **irregular adjective** which is also **long**? 
For now, I found short irregular adjectives (such as good and bad) only, and I'm not sure if something that I'm looking for, exists at all.

I found some lists of irregular adjectives and they don't have even one **long irregular adjective**, but I'm not sure if there's no an exception and it is not listed there.

- [List of irregular adjectives](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CLGG0nPWgAAK_-4.jpg).
- [List of irregular adjectives  source No.2](http://media.llb.re.s3.amazonaws.com/pub/notes/irregularComparative.jpg)

Comment: I think the list of irregular adjectives is (fortunately) quite short:  *good, bad, little, much,* and *far*.

Comment: @Andrew there are a little bit more in this list:)  http://bleemoo.com/wp-content/uploads/positive-comparative-superlative-irregular-adjectives-good-well-bad-smart-icon.jpg  Anyway by my words "short" and "long" I meant to short and long adjectives by the amount of the syllables, as @-Mary-LouA mentioned.

Comment: Why is "small" (in the link above) considered irregular? It perfectly follows the comparative and superlative pattern of one-syllable adjectives.

Comment: [**Latter**](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/latter) is not the comparative of "late" even though it is an adjective, see [EOD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/latter): *Latter means ‘the second-mentioned of two.’ Its use to mean ‘the last-mentioned of three or more’ is common, but is considered incorrect by some because latter means ‘later’ rather than ‘latest.’* Avoid trusting everything you see or find on the net, look for authoritive sources.

Comment: @subtle_sibling  That's an odd list since *older* and *oldest* are perfectly fine.  Actually *elder* and *eldest* are unusual in that there is no root *eld* adjective, at least in modern English.   Plus as Mari-Lou points out, other irregularities.   But either way it's a short list with no "long" words

Comment: I have no idea why they entered this adjective. But I think it's just a mistake there. I think this table would be more correct: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CLGG0nPWgAAK_-4.jpg

Comment: @Mari-LouA later can be also the comparative form of late, based on a lot of dictionaries. See here for example: https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=late

Comment: It's spelled "later" with one "t" not *latter*. And "latterly" is an adverb. This would make a good question, why do we not say "He was born latter than him in age"  Because you can't. This page seems to get it right http://www.really-learn-english.com/later-vs-latter.html

Comment: @subtle_sibling - Shame for having a list like that one and only mentioning it in the comments after someone tried to help you out. -1 for lack of shared research in your question.

Comment: @J.R. it seems that you think that I meant to ask for examples for irregular adjectives (the list in the comment was about this, and only about this). But not, I'm not looking (and I wasn't looking) for short adjectives but for long irregular adjectives. In addition, I did a lot of research before putting the question here. It will be enough if I'll say that I waited two days before posting the question here because I looked for answer. Your things are very insulting, I'm sorry.

Comment: @subtle_s - I don't mean to be "insulting," but mousing-over the downvote button reveals a tooltip that says, "This question does not show any research effort." The issue isn't about how much research you **did**, it's about how much research you have **shown**. That useful link in your comment merits a place in your question; if you edited your question to include the link (instead of only mentioning it in a comment), I'd happily reverse my downvote. Unfortunately, too many ELLers do two days of research only to ask a question 6 lines or less, and the whole community misses out.

Comment: @J.R. I didn't think that I have to bring lists of words that I found not only because that they are on google with one googling of "irregular adjectives lists" but because I thought it is a quite simple question (for those who are native English speakers obviously with a little background in grammar) of yes (+example) or no. Then It's even seems to me not useful to put links to that. But I took my lesson and in the next time I'll link to some material to show some research. This post by itself is already edited based on this lesson.

Comment: At school I was told that only one- and two-syllable adjectives have irregular comparative and superlative. I don't have any references to back that up. though.

Answer (score 1):

I found a relatively longer adj,

> overmuch

It's comparative is

[Overmore](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Overmore)